High CPU by circle animation with gradient
By using the following SwiftUI code the CPU consumption caused by my app is up to 55% when the app is running in XCode (simulator) with an M1.
On the real iPhone the CPU is up to 52%
FYI: the circleProgess is being updated every 0.1 seconds.
Circle()
    .trim(from: 0.0, to: circleProgress)
    .stroke(style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 10, lineCap: .round, lineJoin: .round))
    .fill(Color.pink.gradient)
    .rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: 270.0))
    .animation(.default, value: circleProgress)
    .frame(width: 100, height: 100)

I found out that the high CPU is caused not only but mainly by the Color.pink.gradient line.
If I use the same code but with Color.pink instead of Color.pink.gradient the CPU usage is around 15% on the XCode simulator. On the real device e.g. iPhone 12 the CPU is still up to 35%
Here a reproducible example
struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var someTimer = SomeTimer()
    
    var body: some View {
        AnimatedCircle(circleProgress: $someTimer.circleProgess, size: 100)
        AnimatedCircle(circleProgress: $someTimer.circleProgess, size: 400)
        
        Spacer()
        
        Button(action: someTimer.start, label: {
            Text("Start animation")
        })
        
        Spacer()
    }
}


class SomeTimer : ObservableObject {
    @Published var circleProgess = 1.0
    
    func start() {
        circleProgess = 1.0
        Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.1, repeats: true) {_ in
            self.circleProgess -= 0.001
        }
    }
}

struct AnimatedCircle: View {
    @Binding var circleProgress : Double
    var size : Int
    
    var body: some View {
        Circle()
            .trim(from: 0.0, to: CGFloat(circleProgress))
            .stroke(style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 20, lineCap: .round, lineJoin: .round))
            .fill(Color.pink.gradient)
            //.fill(Color.pink)
            .rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: 270.0))
            .animation(.default, value: CGFloat(circleProgress))
            .frame(width: CGFloat(size), height: CGFloat(size))
    }
}

There is a huge CPU consumption difference by running AnimatedCircle() with
.fill(Color.pink.gradient) or with .fill(Color.pink)
Any ideas how I can use this animation with Color.pink.gradient and still keep the CPU usage much lower than 55%?
Thanks

"I found out that the high CPU is caused mainly by the Color.pink.gradient line." How did you find this out? I highly doubt that is the where the problem is. Please show a [mcve], including how you update circleProgess, so that other people can investigate for themselves where the problem is, instead of just assuming that you're right.

Thanks @Sweeper. I added a minimal example of how it is implemented in general in my app. In the real app the circleProgress is NOT being calculated in the timer itself and the is being stopped after 1 min. This is just an example

Switch ObservedObject to StateObject. StateObject is for initializing and ObservedObject is for passing around

Thanks @loremipsum I changed it to StateObject but CPU is still about 50%

Using your Timer example, I found that the app was using about 47% of a CPU when running on an iPhone 15 simulator with iOS 17.5.
It uses less CPU if you fill the circle first, then apply the trimmed shape as a mask:
Circle()
    .fill(Color.pink.gradient)
    .frame(width: CGFloat(size), height: CGFloat(size))
    .mask {
        Circle()
            .inset(by: 10) // half the line width
            .trim(from: 0.0, to: CGFloat(circleProgress))
            .stroke(style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 20, lineCap: .round, lineJoin: .round))
            .rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: 270.0))
            .animation(.default, value: CGFloat(circleProgress))
    }

In my test, this only used about 8% CPU in the simulator.

THANK YOU @Benzy Neez . You made my day :-). Now the app is causing not even 8% CPU consumpation.
I would like to rank your answer but my reputation is below the CPU percentage my app is running at after your help :-D
But is there an explanation why the circle in my original example performs so badly in comparison to your approach?

@LetsBeHappy Pleased to have been able to help. I guess that in the original implementation, the gradient was being re-computed with every change and this might be slightly CPU intensive. BTW, even with low reputation you should be able to accept the answer by tapping the checkmark, if you're happy that it solves the problem. However, you might have to wait a bit before it lets you.

I accepted your answer. Didn't know I was able to ;-). Now I checked the app on my real device iPhone 12 and your solution is better, but still the CPU in XCode is being shown up to 26%

@LetsBeHappy Are you running a Debug build on the real device? Try changing it to a Release build (you do this by editing the scheme). Ps. Thanks for accepting the answer!

Yes I was running the app with a debug build but a release build did not really helped :-(
